# Show/Display product attribute in description

Tags: magento2, product-attribute

Is there any way to pull or display a product attribute within the product's description?? What we're looking for is something the listings team can use to make a generic product description for lots of very similar products (think USB & network cables) where they can make a simple HTML table in the product description that will directly pull & display attributes, without going through all the fuss of setting up a widget and getting a dev involved for each different family of product. This way the listings team can just copy & paste the description between products, and so long as the attributes are set correctly, it'll 'just work'.

What I am **NOT** looking for :
making custom templates, setting up new widgets, etc, or anything else that would require a dev to make code changes for each variant type.

Answer (score 1):

You try the below mentioned approach

```
$_productCollection = $block->getLoadedProductCollection();

foreach ($_productCollection as $_product)
{
    qtyy= $_product->getData('qty');
    echo "<h5>Quantity = " . $qtyy ."</h5>";
} 

// In the place of qty, you can give your desired attribute
```

PS: You can try this in the desired phtml file and get the required result.

**This code was tested in list.phtml and was successfully displayed in the PLP page!**